# The [getAssociatedToEntities] action in [X] accepts a parameter of type [java.util.List]

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

## Context

I have a project in Grails 2.4.4 using [Spring Security Rest Plugin 1.5.4 for Grails](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-rest) along with [Spring Security Core 2.0.0](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-core) and I'm getting this **warning**:

```
Warning |
The [getAssociatedToEntities] action in [security.UserController] accepts a parameter of type [java.util.List].  Interface types and abstract class types are not supported as command objects.  This parameter will be ignored.

       @Secured("hasAnyRole('READ__USER', 'READ__PROFILE')")
       ^
```

This is the code...

<kbd>BuildConfig</kbd>

```
//...
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:1.5.4"
//...
```

<kbd>UserController</kbd> *(the code where the warning comes from!)*

```
@Secured("hasAnyRole('READ__USER', 'READ__PROFILE')")
def getAssociatedToEntities(List<Long> e, SearchCommand cmd){
    //code omitted
}
```

## Question:

How can I get rid of that warning?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an *Interface* which cannot be used as a *[Command Object](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects)*, try this instead:

Create a Command Object with the list inside

```
import grails.validation.Validateable

@Validateable
class SearchListCommand extends SearchCommand {
  List values
}
```

and replace the declaration of the List with the Command Object in the `getAssociatedToEntities` action

```
def getAssociatedToEntities(SearchListCommand listCommand) { 
     //code omitted...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in list: `@Secured("hasAnyRole(['READ__USER', 'READ__PROFILE'])")`